# Review of UML class Diagram of a ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, uml

I've set up a UML class diagram of my ASP.NET Core Web API that uses Entity Framework,
with Models and Controllers

I would appreciate any feedback

Things i'm concerned about:

1. Multiplicity
2. Relations

[image: UML]

Here's an example of the Bookmark.cs (model):

```
public class Bookmark
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

    }
```

And it's controller (BookmarksController.cs):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BookmarksController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly WebContext _context;

        public BookmarksController(WebContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Bookmarks
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Bookmark>>> GetBookmarks()
        {
            return await _context.Bookmarks.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Bookmarks/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Bookmark>> GetBookmark(int id)
        {
            var bookmark = await _context.Bookmarks.FindAsync(id);

            if (bookmark == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return bookmark;
        }

    
        // POST: api/Bookmarks
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Bookmark>> PostBookmark([FromForm]Bookmark bookmark)
        {
            _context.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetBookmark", new { id = bookmark.Id }, bookmark);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Bookmarks/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteBookmark(int id)
        {
            var bookmark = await _context.Bookmarks.FindAsync(id);
            if (bookmark == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Bookmarks.Remove(bookmark);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the domain, so IMO just some feedbacks about UML syntax:

- Aggregation arrow should have diamond on container (not on contained class).
  [image]
- Higher abstractions should be on higher part of the diagram so inheritance arrows should be from bottom to top. It helps to understand the most important part of the diagram.
- If you can, avoid crossing arrows. You should try to divide your domain not to intertwine.
- Out of diagram scope classes should be grayed or diagram should indicate that they come from a different package (see `ControllerBase` and `DbContext`). It's usefull to understand dependencies.
- Class diagram should state extension points of the architecture. For instance, in the source code of `Bookmark` class, I saw two virtual properties. If your intent is to extend this class, you should indicate it in the diagram. At least with a dummy concrete class example. Usually I use color for it (even if it's out of the standard UML).

Comment: There are some interesting thoughts in this answer. However, composition should only be used if there is an exclusive ownership, with control over the lifecycle of the controlled elements. In OP’s diagram, it’s shared aggregation, with a multiplicity 0..*. This means that the element can exist standalone, and the element can be used in several containers. This is incompatible with composition. A better advice would be to replace it with a simple association, since UML does not define the semantics of shared aggregation.

Comment: Sorry I used composition sample image instead of aggregation one. I fix it.